# docker-compose how to access module from another project?

Tags: python, docker

I have 2 projects and i want project two to access functions in project one, how to do that?

this is are my simple files :)

project

```
root
---one
------main.py
---two
------main.py
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  one:
    build: ./one
  two:
    build: ./two
```

two/main.py

```
from one.main import myfun

myfun()
```

error from docker logs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from one.main import myfun
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'one'
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after some search and David Maze help

I had to change docker-compose file, Dockerfile for project `two` and move it to main directory.

new docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  one:
    build: ./one
  two:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-two
```

new Dockerfile-two

```
FROM python:3.6
WORKDIR /two

COPY /two /two/
COPY /one /two/one/

COPY /two/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "/two/main.py"]
```

It has to be in the main root to have access to all folders.
Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

One container can't directly access or import code in another container, any more than if the two Python applications were running on physically separate machines.

Start by reading through the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org), and in particular, the guide on [Packaging and distributing projects](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/).  You should treat your `one` application as an ordinary Python library; it should have a `setup.py` script and so on.

If `one` is runnable as an application in its own right, then `one/Dockerfile` can be extremely straightforward:

```sh
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN pip install .
CMD some_console_script
```

There are a couple of ways to get this library into the application `two`.  One is to run, outside of Docker:

```sh
cd ../one
python setup.py bdist_wheel
mv dist/one-*.whl ../two/one.whl
cd ../two
docker build -t me/two .
```

That Dockerfile can then manually install the built wheel file:

```sh
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /app
COPY one.whl .
RUN pip install ./one.whl
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . ./
CMD ["./two.py"]
```

You can also use a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to do this in one command, using a fully isolated environment.  The Dockerfile should be in the `root` directory in your diagram; it can be somewhere else, but you will need to use the `root` path in the `docker build` command and all `COPY` paths will be relative to `root`.

```sh
FROM python:3.8 AS build-one
WORKDIR /one
COPY one ./
RUN python setup.py bdist_wheel \
 && mv dist/one-*.whl one.whl

FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-one /one/one.whl .
RUN pip install ./one.whl
COPY two/requirements.txt ./
# and repeating the rest of the "just build `two`" Dockerfile
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) The best way for me is to create a common_lib and share it with python projects + changing Dockerfile + Docker-compose file. I'll post it the new files beneath. cheers